# Adding data types in a function

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and learning about data types.  I am attempting to do a simple problem, but I cant seem to grasp the bigger picture.  I have a data type of LengthUnit which resembles inches, feet, and yards.  I want to make a function that takes a list of lists of LengthUnits and converts them to inches and sums all elements.

I created a helper function convert, which converts the LengthUnit to inches. I also have addLengths which accepts two LengthUnits and adds them up.  I cant seem to get the output I am looking for.  Here is what I have:

```
data LengthUnit =  INCH  Int | FOOT  Int | YARD  Int
                   deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

convert :: LengthUnit -> Int  
convert (INCH x) =  (x) 
convert (FOOT x) =  (x * 12)
convert (YARD x) =  (x * 36)

-- addLengths 
addLengths :: LengthUnit -> LengthUnit -> LengthUnit
addLengths x y = INCH ((convert x) + (convert y))


-- addAllLengths
--addAllLengths :: Foldable t => [t LengthUnit] -> LengthUnit
addAllLengths list = let nList = map convert list
                     in foldr addLengths 0 nList
```

From the above I get an error: Couldn't match type 'Int' with 'LengthUnit'.  Any help would be appreciated.

I'm looking to get something like this:

```
addAllLengths [[FOOT 2], [FOOT 2, INCH 2],[]]
INCH 50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
addAllLengths list = foldr addLengths (INCH 0) (concat list)
```

`concat` turns `[[FOOT 2], [FOOT 2, INCH 2],[]]` into `[FOOT 2, FOOT 2, INCH 2]`, and then `foldr addLengths (INCH 0)` turns that into `INCH 50`.

Comment: Thank, I didn't know about concat.  That would come in handy